# Can an email/alert be configured for a site that hasn't been modified in 6 months?

Tags: email, alert, sharepoint-server, content

Here is my requirement:

We have a SharePoint 2010 intranet. Content owners are responsible for their specific site content whether that is document libraries/content on the pages, etc...

Is there a way to configure an alert or email to only content users whose sites haven't been modified in 6 months?

Thanks,
Ninel

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature in Central administration that handles this to a degree, called Confirm Site Use and Deletion (found in Application Management). When configured, It will send notifications periodically to the site owners asking them to ensure the site is still being used. It can be configured as well to automatically delete the site collection if they aren't or no responses pile up.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262420(v=office.14).aspx